# Disable Teams Site Creation

Tags: powershell, provisioning, microsoft-teams

My mind is blown here. A regular use just created a Team from within MS Teams client application. This then created an O365 Group with inbox. It also created a new SharePoint site collection and locked out the administrators.

This is a governance nightmare and circumvents our security model, our information architecture, our navigation and branding. What is Microsoft thinking?!

O365 groups and SharePoint site collections should only be created by Admins (EVER). How do you disable the creation of 'Teams' and resulting site collections from the MS Teams client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a script that disables Teams creation from MS teams. Actually, you are still able to create them if you are in a specified group:

http://laurentschoenaers.be/2018/08/20/office-365-microsoft-teams-prevent-team-creation/

There was also an issue with the cmdlet `Get-AzureADDirectorySetting` which this post answers (Just call `AzureADPreview\Connect-AzureAD` instead of just `Connect-AzureAD`)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/189

Answer (score 1):

Users probably create this Team Site on https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx right?

For hiding this option go:

> SharePoint Online Central Administration > Settings > Site Creation >
>   Hide the Create  site command.

Here you can set Site and Subsite creation command.

[image]

Comment: They are using the Teams app but I disabled subsites creation from this menu, thx!

Comment: You're welcome. If it watisfied you, you can make this as answer.